GCP Cloud Run seems to not be serving the proper revision
I have a simple FastAPI API deployed using GCP Cloud Run, which serves as the back-end of a React webapp hosted in Firebase. The system was working fine and I would regularly create new revisions using the following command:
gcloud builds submit --tag $(DOCKER_IMAGE)  
gcloud run deploy $(API_NAME) --image $(DOCKER_IMAGE) --port 8000 --memory $(API_MEMORY) --cpu $(API_CPU) --max-instances $(API_MAX_SCALE) --timeout 5m

Even without changing the image tag, the Cloud Run service would get updated with the latest changes of the back-end. However, this failed one day without doing any changes on the system, and since then I haven't managed to make it work even updating the tag at every deploy.
The error I get is the following, which is an error I had seen in a former revision and fixed already, which makes me suspect Cloud Run is not using the proper revision. The Poetry warning is also something I had already addressed.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'serving'


I can find the images in the registry and the latest tag (0.2.0, which I'm trying to deploy) runs as expected locally.
> gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/image2paint/image2paint-api 
DIGEST        TAGS   TIMESTAMP
cead5c33f468  0.2.0  2024-08-03T17:32:32
fa0f020fc6a9  0.1.1  2024-08-03T17:16:11
b99f9ae7f147         2024-08-02T11:35:09
ba561bcbe110  0.1.0  2024-08-02T10:42:50


If I check the Yaml of the failing service in Cloud Run UI, I can see that the image is using the expected tag (0.2.0), and the last revision (which is also the selected revision according to the UI) has the proper sha (starting by cead5c33f468).
I'm new to Cloud Run and I'm not sure how to proceed debugging this issue, especially since I'm unable to understand what caused it. Could this be related to Docker layer caching? Help is much appreciated :)

If you look at the "Revisions" tav in the Cloud Run UI, which revision is actually serving traffic? If the container you're trying to deploy fails to start, cloud run won't send any traffic to the new container.

No revisions are serving traffic, when I suspected this could be a caching issue I deleted all previous images from the Container Registry, and even changed the tag of the image to avoid any caching (my naive solution). I don't really mind the request answer at the Firebase side (it is an expected 404 now), I'd like to understand why the difference between running the gcr.io image locally and when Cloud Run tries to start it (the two screenshots above). Should I explicitly add anything related to the healthiness & readiness probes? They were working well at the beginning tho

Cloud Run captures the image and its digest when you create a new revision. If you check the revision details, it will always list the image by digest and not by tag.
What likely happened here is that your traffic configuration was updated to point to a specific revision (served by a specific digest) rather than pointing to the latest revision  This feature is used so you can test new versions before directing traffic to them) If that's the case, running gcloud run services update-traffic --to-latest will switch it back so that all traffic goes to the latest revision.

The error screenshot I shared belongs to the latest revision, I validated it in the UI (the latest revision was checked in the Revisions tab, and all revisions had 0% traffic). Actually when I run the command you shared it fails with the same error, which makes sense because it is doing the same than what Cloud Run is trying to do (that is, try to direct the traffic to the latest revision, which  is not possible because the latest revision is failing with the error above).

Does the docker image start if you try to run it locally?

It does, yes. The black (translucid) screenshot I shared belongs to my local machine (I realize now I cut the command out, but it is a "docker run"). The screenshot shows the API started as expected, and I was able to open the Swagger UI provided by FastAPI in my browser and successfully try all my endpoints.
